# How to change the blob size into 5D

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, video-processing, deep-learning, caffe

In general, the dimension of blobs for input data is 4D.
How can I set the size blob in training prototxt file?
The input data are saved in HDF5 format with 5D including `batch`x`channel`x`temporal`x`height`x`weight`

The error I got is

```
I0520 21:39:35.705278 30447 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv1
I0520 21:39:35.705286 30447 net.cpp:381] conv1 <- data
I0520 21:39:35.705294 30447 net.cpp:339] conv1 -> conv1
I0520 21:39:35.705307 30447 net.cpp:113] Setting up conv1
F0520 21:39:35.705329 30447 base_conv_layer.cpp:14] Check failed: 4 == bottom[0]->num_axes() (4 vs. 5) Input must have 4 axes, corresponding to (num, channels, height, width)
```

It seems the input blob dimension should be 4.

Is there any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: if you have `data` as the `"top"` of an `"HDF5Data"` layer, then the shape of `data` should be **automatically** determined by caffe according to the shape of the data stored in the corresponding HDF5 file.

Comment: what version of caffe are you using? where did you clone it from? what branch? when did you clone it? AFAIK, current "master" branch of BVLC/caffe does not have this check.

Comment: I use the LSTM version which is release in CVPR 2015. The link is https://github.com/LisaAnne/lisa-caffe-public/tree/lstm_video_deploy.
Do you know which version of caffe support this format?

Comment: I don't know this branch. you'll have to figure how it fits into the general caffe framework...

Comment: I'm curious about whether there is a branch which would determine the shape of data automatically.

Comment: your problem is not to determine the blob shape: caffe knows it. The error you get is that your branch only supports 4D blobs, while you are feeding it with 5D blob (and even your caffe is able to determine this).

Comment: I find this version which said it support N-D blob. https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/releases
I will try it later.

Comment: Did u find a solution? @ycliu5037 Cause I am interested in this as well!